# Update subscriber fields in All Subscribers List

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, marketing-cloud-connect

In Service Cloud I have specific fields on the Contact for bounces. But when the Contact changes his/her email address these fields are refreshed. I want to update the All Subscribers list status accordingly. I know that this can be done through the Extract Transfer Import flow but I am wondering if this can be avoided. Is there anything from the Marketing Cloud Connect that does this automatically that can be leveraged?

Another thing I am wondering, according to this Salesforce slide it says that when using a sendable data extension the email will be sent to the email on the All Subscriber list. However, when using journey builder it seems as if this is not happening. It actually updates the All Subscribers List with the new email address and also sends to this email address.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are quite a few questions but they can be answered in 2 basic answers:

1. **Marketing Cloud Connect updating subscriber data:** there is currently no functionality that does this. If you have developer resources at hand you can leverage SQL to identify changed attributes and SSJS (Serverside JavaScript) to execute SOAP API calls for subscriber updates in an automation. This would keep data within the application. There is an [idea in Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003Re4QAE) you are invited to vote for too make this process easier. If clutter or leftover files on the FTP are your main concern you can enable an data extract activity type through support that deletes files on the FTP based on a naming pattern. If you put this at the end of the automation you can clean up the exported files. If data replication to an external service like the FTP is an issue you need the above mentioned SSJS or an API integration straight from Sales/Service Cloud, which would count against your API limits.
2. **Journey Builder sends updating email addresses:** the observed behaviour is correct. Emails in journeys are triggered sends. For journey builder sends they are auto configured to update subscriber data. This behavior for triggered sends is described in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_triggered_emails.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) under the heading "Destination Management".